# Extending android surface view for camera to support all devices

Tags: android, android-layout, android-camera, surfaceview, surfaceholder

I have created a `CameraSurfaceView` class which provides logic for implementing the camera preview. Everything works fine on the devices I have tried. Nexus 5, Nexus 5X, Nexus 6P and even a Samsung Galaxy S5.

But for some reason on the Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge, I get a Runtime exception of

> android.hardware.Camera.native_setParameters(Native Method)

I have narrowed it down to the the following in class

> parameters.setPictureSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);

Here is my class:

```
public class CameraSurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private Camera mCamera;
    private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
    private List<Camera.Size> mSupportedPreviewSizes;
    private Camera.Size mPreviewSize;

    public CameraSurfaceView(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        mCamera = camera;
        mSurfaceHolder = getHolder();
        mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        mSupportedPreviewSizes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        if (mSurfaceHolder.getSurface() == null) {
            // preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }

        try {
            // stop preview before making changes
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Timber.e(e, e.getMessage());
        }

        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or reformatting changes here
        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
            parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
            parameters.setPictureSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);

            if (parameters.getSupportedFocusModes()
                    .contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE)) {
                parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
            }

            mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Timber.e(e, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        final int width = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
        final int height = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);

        if (mSupportedPreviewSizes != null) {
            mPreviewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(mSupportedPreviewSizes, width, height);
        }

        float ratio;
        if (mPreviewSize.height >= mPreviewSize.width) {
            ratio = (float) mPreviewSize.height / (float) mPreviewSize.width;
        } else {
            ratio = (float) mPreviewSize.width / (float) mPreviewSize.height;
        }

        // One of these methods should be used, second method squishes preview slightly
        setMeasuredDimension(width, (int) (width * ratio));
//        setMeasuredDimension((int) (width * ratio), height);
    }

    private Camera.Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Camera.Size> sizes, int w, int h) {
        final double aspectTolerance = 0.1;
        double targetRatio = (double) h / w;

        if (sizes == null) {
            return null;
        }

        Camera.Size optimalSize = null;
        double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

        int targetHeight = h;

        for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
            double ratio = (double) size.height / size.width;
            if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > aspectTolerance) {
                continue;
            }
            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }

        if (optimalSize == null) {
            minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
                if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                    optimalSize = size;
                    minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                }
            }
        }

        return optimalSize;
    }
}
```

How do I set the picture size correctly for this device or any others with the same issue?

Does anyone have a good example of Camera SurfaceView logic that would work for most devices?

Thanks.

Comment: I faced with the same issue and solved with using screen Width and Height. Don't trust to preview for sizes. It can be faulty for most of old devices.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was using the `supportedPreviewSizes` to set the picture size as opposed to the `supportedPictureSizes` in the camera parameters.

Below is my new CameraSurfaceView class:

```
public class CameraSurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private Camera mCamera;
    private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
    private List<Camera.Size> mSupportedPreviewSizes;
    private List<Camera.Size> mSupportedPictureSizes;
    private Camera.Size mPreviewSize;
    private Camera.Size mPictureSize;

    public CameraSurfaceView(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        mSurfaceHolder = getHolder();
        mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);

        mCamera = camera;
        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();

        mSupportedPreviewSizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        mSupportedPictureSizes = parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes();

        if (parameters.getSupportedFocusModes()
                .contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE)) {
            parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
        }

        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        if (mSurfaceHolder.getSurface() == null) {
            // preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }

        try {
            // stop preview before making changes
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Timber.e(e, e.getMessage());
        }

        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or reformatting changes here
        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
            parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
            parameters.setPictureSize(mPictureSize.width, mPictureSize.height);

            mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Timber.e(e, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        final int width = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
        final int height = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);

        if (mSupportedPreviewSizes != null) {
            mPreviewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(mSupportedPreviewSizes, width, height);
        }

        if (mSupportedPictureSizes != null) {
            mPictureSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(mSupportedPictureSizes, mPreviewSize.width,
                    mPreviewSize.height);
        }

        float ratio;
        if (mPreviewSize.height >= mPreviewSize.width) {
            ratio = (float) mPreviewSize.height / (float) mPreviewSize.width;
        } else {
            ratio = (float) mPreviewSize.width / (float) mPreviewSize.height;
        }

        setMeasuredDimension(width, (int) (width * ratio));
    }

    private Camera.Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Camera.Size> sizes, int w, int h) {
        final double aspectTolerance = 0.1;
        double targetRatio = (double) h / w;

        if (sizes == null) {
            return null;
        }

        Camera.Size optimalSize = null;
        double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

        int targetHeight = h;

        for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
            double ratio = (double) size.height / size.width;
            if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > aspectTolerance) {
                continue;
            }
            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }

        if (optimalSize == null) {
            minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
                if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                    optimalSize = size;
                    minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                }
            }
        }

        return optimalSize;
    }
}
```